How to Select an Area in Mapbox Using Selenium with Java?
I am working on automating the selection of an area on a Mapbox map using Selenium with Java. I’ve tried multiple approaches, including using the Action class and JavaScript, but none of them have worked so far.
Below are the methods I have attempted:
Method 1: Using JavaScriptExecutor
clickOnCanvasMethod1(WebElement canvas, int x, int y) {  
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
    String script = "var canvas = arguments[0];"  
            + "var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();"  
            + "var x = arguments[1];"  
            + "var y = arguments[2];"  
            + "canvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {"  
            + "    clientX: rect.left + x,"  
            + "    clientY: rect.top + y,"  
            + "    bubbles: true"  
            + "}));";  
    js.executeScript(script, canvas, x, y);  
}

Method 2: Using Action Class
clickOnCanvasMethod2(WebElement canvas) {  
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);  
    actions.moveToElement(canvas, 200, 200)  
            .clickAndHold()  
            .moveByOffset(100, 100)  
            .release()  
            .perform();  
}

Method 3: Using JavaScript for Mouse Events
clickOnCanvasMethod3(WebElement canvas) {  
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
    String script = "var canvas = arguments[0];"  
            + "var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();"  
            + "canvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', {"  
            + "    clientX: rect.left + 200,"  
            + "    clientY: rect.top + 200,"  
            + "    bubbles: true"  
            + "}));"  
            + "canvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {"  
            + "    clientX: rect.left + 300,"  
            + "    clientY: rect.top + 300,"  
            + "    bubbles: true"  
            + "}));"  
            + "canvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup', {"  
            + "    clientX: rect.left + 300,"  
            + "    clientY: rect.top + 300,"  
            + "    bubbles: true"  
            + "}));";  
    js.executeScript(script, canvas);  
}  

None of these methods seem to work as expected.
Reference URL: Mapbox Draw Example
Could someone please help me identify the issue or suggest an alternative approach to select an area on the map?
Thank you for your help!

Here's a simple example using ActionChains().
In this case, you first have to switch to the IFRAME that contains the CANVAS. Once there, we grab the CANVAS element and then start clicking. move_to_element_with_offset() moves to the center of the element so I chose -50 and 50 as my x,y options forming a square. The fifth click is on the starting point to close the square. You can put a breakpoint on the print() line to see the final state.

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

driver.switch_to.frame("demo")
canvas = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "canvas")
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(canvas, -50, -50).click().perform()
action.move_to_element_with_offset(canvas, -50, 50).click().perform()
action.move_to_element_with_offset(canvas, 50, 50).click().perform()
action.move_to_element_with_offset(canvas, 50, -50).click().perform()
action.move_to_element_with_offset(canvas, -50, -50).click().perform()
print("Done")


If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.
